# How to gather score values from perspective api in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this JSON data:

```
{
  "attributeScores": {
    "SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT": {
      "spanScores": [
        {
          "begin": 0,
          "end": 12,
          "score": {
            "value": 0.058843683,
            "type": "PROBABILITY"
          }
        }
      ],
      "summaryScore": {
        "value": 0.058843683,
        "type": "PROBABILITY"
      }
    },
    "IDENTITY_ATTACK_EXPERIMENTAL": {
      "spanScores": [
        {
          "begin": 0,
          "end": 12,
          "score": {
            "value": 0.012206113,
            "type": "PROBABILITY"
          }
        }
      ],
      "summaryScore": {
        "value": 0.012206113,
        "type": "PROBABILITY"
      }
    }
  },
  "languages": [
    "en"
  ],
  "detectedLanguages": [
    "en"
  ]
}
```

How can I extract the score values from this data, such as this?

```
value1 = 0.058843683
value2 = 0.012206113
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. Do you know how to get data from a dictionary, or from a list? Do you know how to read and parse a JSON file? If you don't know all of those things, then that shows you what you need to research. If you do know, then I don't understand what the difficulty is - try to write the code, and ask a specific question after you have tried to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how you identify if it is toxic, but you can get those values through:

```
for k,v in data['attributeScores'].items():
    print( k, v['summaryScore']['value'] )
```